# how to make custom URL with custom routing in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have problem to make custom url in mvc. I want to make url like this one:

`http://www.domainname.com/directory/bysearch/value1/value2`

but its make like this

`http://www.domainname.com/directory/bysearch?txtaddress=value1&searchString=value2`

and

RouteConfig.cs code

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Directory",
           url: "Directory/{qualifier}/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}/{v6}/{v7}/{v8}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Directory",
               action = "index",
               qualifier = UrlParameter.Optional,
               v1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
               v2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
               v3 = UrlParameter.Optional,
               v4 = UrlParameter.Optional,
               v5 = UrlParameter.Optional,
               v6 = UrlParameter.Optional,
               v7 = UrlParameter.Optional,
               v8 = UrlParameter.Optional
           });
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DirectorySerach",
    url: "Directory/bysearch/{v1}/{v2}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Directory",
        action = "Search",
        v1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        v2 = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string qualifier, string v1, string v2, string v3, string v4, string v5, string v6, string searchString, int page = 1)
    {
       // code logic here
       return View();
    }
public ActionResult Search(string v1 = null,string v2 = null)
{
   //code logic here
    return View();
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("search","Directory", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="c-checkbox">
            <input id="chkOnline" name="chkOnline" class="c-check" type="checkbox">
            <label for="chkOnline" class="c-font-thin c-font-17">
                <span></span>
                <span class="box"></span> Online
                <span class="check"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       @Html.TextBox("txtaddress", null, new { @class = "form-control c-square c-theme input-lg", @placeholder = "Address OR ZIP/Postal Code OR City" })
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg c-square">
        @Html.TextBox("searchString", null, new { @class = "form-control c-square c-theme input-lg", @placeholder = "Enter Keyword" })
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-square c-btn-uppercase c-font-bold" type="submit">Go!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

please help/guide me, where i am wrong or what is the problem. and how to resolve.
i appreciate your value able time and effort. thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the first route in your definitions? It needs to be before the 'Default' route. Also your should remove both `UrlParameter.Optional` (only the last route can be optional)

Comment: Also are you expecting the values of the textboxes to be in the routes? In which case, you need to name the textboxes to match the route parameters - i.e. @Html.TextBox("v1", ...)` etc (and remove the route parameters in `BeginForm()`

Comment: thanks. @Stephen Muecke , yes i want text box values in route. and i have more than 1 cutom routes in routeconfig. but others are working.

Comment: yes, its before the default route. but one of the route is before that route.

Comment: i have update my question, with 2 different route and actions. the complete code now updated.

Comment: You need to put the `DirectorySerach` route before the `Directory` route (see my answer) And you `Login` route makes no sense - it does not have an `{id}` parameter and it could never be hit anyway (anything matching that would always go to the `SmallBiz` route)

Comment: And you need to remove all the `UrlParameter.Optional` from your `Directory` (except perhaps the last one) - only the last parameter can be optional.

Comment: i placed directorysearch route at 1st. but its hit the index action in directorycontroller instead of search.

Comment: And did you make the other changes as per the answer?

Comment: yes, i make the same changes as you mentioned in answer, still problem. and i need the searchbox value in url but not the names. the url now its make http://localhost:64668/Directory/search?v1=val1111&v2=val2222 but it should be http://localhost:64668/Directory/bysearch/val1111/val2222

Comment: And it will be if you use the code in my answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make clean URl then you need to craete URl manually, As Form Submit will always create query string.

So remove your form and replace button with hyperlink. and write click event on link.

```
@Html.TextBox("v1", null, new {  })
@Html.TextBox("v2", null, new {  })
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary">GO</a>
```

Now Write a function which will create URl

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSearch').on('click',function(){
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Search", "Directory")'; 
    var gettext1= $('#v1').val();
      var gettext2= $('#v2').val();
       if(gettext1){
        baseUrl  += '/'+gettext1;
       }else{
        baseUrl  += "/0";
      }
      if(gettext2){
        baseUrl  +="/"+ gettext2;
       }else{
        baseUrl  += "/0";
      }
    location.href=baseUrl;
    });
});
</script>
```

here you need to handle **0**. as if user doesn't enter anything in textbox then I'm passing 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried the above code as it is but do nothing when click on go button.

Comment: You can just simplify all this to simply `$('#btnSearch').click(function() { var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("BySearch", "Directory"); var url = baseUrl + '/' + $('#v1').val() + '/' + $('#v2').val(); location.href=url; });` (and delete the `new { id="txt1" }` etc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for good point, Amrit kumar can you update your answer in detail so it will be easy for me.

Comment: i just comment all of my code in view and use your updated code but no action call and no url change.

Comment: @adnan : did you include Jquery in your view and check browser console for any error ..

Comment: yes, i include the jquery file, but in my project there is jquery version change its 2.1.4 but also i create new project and add the same code you provided in answer, here is the same version as you mention, but still no action call or url change.its show this exception in browser console on page load where i use code: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @adnan: update this line `var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Search", "Directory")';`

Comment: yes, now its done and hits the action, and make perfect url as i desired. but 1 problem only, in url it always pass 0/0 instead of textbox values.http://localhost:64668/Directory/bysearch/0/0

Comment: @adnan: if you paste the as it is, then it should work , otherwise check the id of your textbox. as I'm getting perfect url `http://localhost:59548/Directory/Search/data1/data2`.  Or show me snapshot of your `view` code

Comment: now its good, and working. thanks @AmitKumar for your valuable time and effort thanks again.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  thanks for your help in route settings.i appreciate your time and effort.